# PHP 7 and strict "resource" types

Tags: php, php-7

Does PHP 7 support strict typing for resources? If so, how?

For example:

```
    declare (strict_types=1);

    $ch = curl_init ();
    test ($ch);

    function test (resource $ch)
    {

    }
```

The above will give the error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to test() must be an instance of resource, resource given

A var_dump on `$ch` reveals it to be **resource(4, curl)**, and the manual says `curl_init ()` returns a resource.

Is it at all possible to strictly type the `test()` function to support the `$ch variable`?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

PHP does not have a [type hint for resources](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/scalar_type_hints) because

> No type hint for resources is added, as this would prevent moving from resources to objects for existing extensions, which some have already done (e.g. GMP).

However, you can use [`is_resource()`](http://php.net/is_resource) within the function/method body to verify the passed argument and handle it as needed. A reusable version would be an assertion like this:

```
function assert_resource($resource)
{
    if (false === is_resource($resource)) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException(
            sprintf(
                'Argument must be a valid resource type. %s given.',
                gettype($resource)
            )
        );
    }
}
```

which you could then use within your code like that:

```
function test($ch)
{
    assert_resource($ch);
    // do something with resource
}
```

Comment: It's worth pointing out that this `is_resource` check has the same limitation as you quoted from the RFC: when that type of resource is replaced with an object in a future version of PHP, the code will break. There is currently [a proposal that object-based file handles in particular will return `true` from `is_resource`](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/resource_to_object_conversion), but other types of resource which are converted will _not_.

Answer (score 20):

`resource` is not a [valid type](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration.types) so it's assumed to be a class name as per good old PHP/5 type hints. But `curl_init()` does not return an object instance.

As far as I know there's not way to specify a resource. It probably wouldn't be so useful since not all resources are identical: a resource generated by `fopen()` would be useless for `oci_parse()`.

If you want to check the resource in the function body, you can use [get_resource_type()](https://php.net/get_resource_type) (with [is_resource()](https://php.net/is_resource) to prevent errors), as in:

```
is_resource($ch) && get_resource_type($ch) === 'curl'
```

---

Starting on PHP/8.0, [`curl_init()`](https://www.php.net/curl_init) returns an object so you can now use [`CurlHandle`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.curlhandle.php) as type hint,