# How to add 'stream resource' return type to function in PHP

Tags: php, function, file, return-type

I am trying to add a **return type** to my function that is getting a file of the **resource** **type**, but I cant figure out what return type to add? I get an error that my return is a **resource** and is expected to be a **resource** witch confuses me :P

Here is my function (more stuff happens in this function to create the filepath but I left it out since it is irrelevant.

```
private function getMappingExportFile(JobParameters $jobParameters): \resource
{
    return fopen($filePath,"r");
}
```

This is the error I am getting

```
::getMappingExportFile() must be an instance of resource, resource returned
```

If if remove the return type everything works fine, but I prefer to make my code more strict.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP 7 and strict "resource" types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38429595/php-7-and-strict-resource-types)

Answer (score 0):

As of March 2023 this still seems impossible.
As @Keutelvocht commented, more info on why this is, can be found in [PHP 7 and strict "resource" types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38429595/php-7-and-strict-resource-types)

---

However, you can still (softly) typehint this using a docblock above your function.

```
/**
 * @param JobParameters $jobParameters
 * @return resource
 */
private function getMappingExportFile(JobParameters $jobParameters)
{
    return fopen($filePath,"r");
}
```