# Strict type declarations and resource

Tags: php

What data type would I use if I want to return a resource within a function?

This isn't allowed and causes a fatal error:

```
function test():resource{...}
```

Comment: What is your PHP version ? What is the returned resource ?

Comment: @Syscall, It's 7.4 and the resource returned should be from `odbc_connect`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP 7 and strict "resource" types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38429595/php-7-and-strict-resource-types)