# fopen return type declaration

Tags: php

i use fopen to get a FilePointer and everything works great. But i want to set the Return type of my function and this makes me confusing.

definitin fopen: Returns a file pointer resource on success, or FALSE on error.

```
/**
 * @param File $file
 * @return false|resource
 * @comment not able to set "resource" as return type
 */
private function openFilePointer(File $file)
{
    $fileStreamMode = 'r';
    return fopen($file->getPathname(), $fileStreamMode);
}
```

if i try to set the return type only boolean is suggested by phpstrom.

```
private function openFilePointer(File $file): bool|resource 
{
  // resource is not available as type?
  ...
}
```

is it possible to set the resource as type?

same happens when using Flysystems readstream method (returns resource or bool), i think they also use fopen intern

[image: PHPStorm Screenshot]

i tried out to set mixed as return type, but PhpStorm is giving a typehint to boolean.

[image]

Comment: from [the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.declarations.php): `mixed` is equivalent to the union type object|resource|array|string|int|float|bool|null. Available as of PHP 8.0.0.

Comment: tried out this, but phpstorm allready give typehints:
"Type can be narrowed to 'bool' "

see the screenshot in the description

Comment: [Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38429595/php-7-and-strict-resource-types). I think nothing has changed.

Comment: thanks for the answers, i will not add an return type declaration and i gotta stand with the  typehint warnings in PHPStrom