# What is the type of the handle given back by fopen()?

Tags: php, phpstan, php-8.2

I have this code:

```php
class CsvWriter
{
    private $handle;


    public function openToFile($filePath): void
    {
        $this->handle = fopen($filePath, 'wb+');
        if (false === $this->handle) {
            throw new FileException('Could not open file ' . $filePath, 8788);
        }
    }
}
```

PHPStan complains that

> `Property App\Domain\Csv\CsvWriter::$handle` has no type specified.

Well that is true, but what type is it?

```
private resource $handle;
```

does not work.

**What is the correct property of my $handle?**

Comment: PHP does not have a type hint for resources. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38430606/2499739

Comment: ok thank you , the information free "mixed" does the trick to pacify phpstan though.

Comment: Also note, a file handle is not a file handler. The file handle is a resource and a handler would be a class or callback handling the handle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not everything can be expressed as first-class type annotation. In those cases, a docblock comment can be used instead:

```php
/** @var resource|false */
private $handle = false;
```