What's the correct way to specify the `resource` data type in PHP?
If I open a file using fopen, it returns a resource. This type is quite special and does not appear to have a way to specify.
Assume I have a function like
public function putBlob($stream) {}

How do I say that $stream must be resource? The resource type does not appear to exist, at least my IDE doesn't recognize it.
The PHP stdlib appears to do it like this:
/**
 * Binary-safe file read
 * @link https://php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php
 * @param resource $stream &fs.file.pointer;
 * @param int $length <p>
 * Up to length number of bytes read.
 * </p>
 * @return string|false the read string or false on failure.
 */
function fread($stream, int $length): string|false {}

Which I can also do:
/**
 * @param resource $stream
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function putBlob(mixed $stream) {}

But it does not prevent anyone from passing something that is not a resource.
How can I make sure only a resource is ever passed to this function?
If it can't be specified statically, is it possible to detect it at runtime?

I was thinking about this this morning! Turns out there isn't a resource type hint because of extensions shenanigans. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38429595/php-7-and-strict-resource-types

Oh, great, that's the same question, I did not manage to find it before asking. Thanks. Exactly what I need.
